# parse_mode и span

Tags: python, html, telegram-bot, telebot

Пытаюсь преобразовать строку для тг-бота с помощью parse_mode='html', но постоянно выходит ошибка для тега span. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить эту ошибку.

```
def menu(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<a href="https://cook-and-clean.ru/rulka-v-pive/" itemprop="url" rel="bookmark"><span itemprop="headline">Рулька в пиве</span></a>', parse_mode='html')
```

ERROR - TeleBot: "Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse entities: Tag "span" must have class "tg-spoiler" at byte offset 80"

Comment: ну так в ошибке же сказано, что тэг `span` должен иметь класс `tg-spoiler`. Исправьте на `<span class="tg-spoiler" itemprop="headline">Рулька в пиве</span>`

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!